# jewel-toned shirts or jewel-tone shirts?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

"Before Rand could apologize or engage further, Tanner and Betsy arrived together, looking like a *Vogue* spread - crisp slacks and jewel-toned shirts"... p.429 Gone Girl by Gillian Flynn.

I have always seen the latter version of this adjective, but in the book that I am reading it is written with a -*d* at the end (jewel-tone**d**). Furthermore, I have encountered a few other adjectives in the same book that the author has chosen to spell in a similar way. Does the -d make a difference? Is it dialect?

Comment: We speak of a _coloured_ shirt, not a _colour_ one. _Tone_ here means colour, so why should it not be used in the same way?

Comment: Good point, @KateBunting , but there are many webpages that don't share this opinion. Take Your Dictionary (https://www.yourdictionary.com/jewel-tone) for instance, they use *jewel-tone* in all their examples. The same goes for many online clothing stores, eg. Etsy (https://www.etsy.com/market/jewel_tone_shirts). Can you please explain this?

Comment: I would say _jewel-toned_ as well. Actually, I wouldn’t – jewel isn’t a tone I’m familiar with, so the entire word doesn’t make much sense to me, and I’d never use it. But out of these two options, I’d use the one with the _-d_. The one without is by no means wrong, but the one with feels more natural. @KateBunting We do say a technicolour shirt, though (not a \*technicoloured one), and definitely a monotone (not \*monotoned) one as well. It’s not as simple as just comparing with the simplex adjectives.

Comment: I can't explain it - it seems odd to me.